# php hangs while executing exec in windows

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am converting a video using ffmpeg from php in Windows using following code

```
<?php

exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32k -r 25 -s 480x360 -vcodec h264 -qscale 2.5      output.flv');

?>
```

While converting script hangs until conversion completed.

What can i do about it? So that it can run in background

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a ffmpeg process in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198052/run-a-ffmpeg-process-in-the-background)

Comment: Are you calling this script from a website and you dont want the site to hang whilst the video encodes?

Comment: @Rich yes, Actually i am running it from localhost

Answer (score 0):

If your system is Linux I would just background the task by adding ' &' to the end of the command.

```
exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32k -r 25 -s 480x360 -vcodec h264 -qscale 2.5 output.flv &');
```

Or to be even more thorough (i.e. even if apache dies the file will still be transcoded):

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32k -r 25 -s 480x360 -vcodec h264 -qscale 2.5 output.flv > /dev/null 2>&1 &"')
```

Don't you have to call ffmpeg.exe on windows?

Comment: when i tried to run in ubuntu 12.04 it said "This program is deprecated ***"