# how to install ffmpeg php extension on plesk centos7

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos, centos7, plesk

please help me installing FFMEPG,
i have instilled it  but there is no extension in *php* setting.

in php.d ffmepg is not there.

anyone one know how to *install it*.

Comment: FFmpeg does not include any PHP extensions. You need a third-party wrapper if you want to do that. See the [tag:ffmpeg-php] and [tag:php-ffmpeg] tags. Otherwise, just execute the `ffmpeg` executable directly in the script. See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For PHP >=7.0, simply use composer:**

```
# /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
```

**For earlier PHP versions:**

1. Make sure [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) is enabled:

```
# yum repolist | grep epel
*epel/x86_64 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - 12559
```

If it is not, enable it as follows:

```
# yum install epel* -y
```

2. Enable RPM Fusion:

```
# yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
# yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

3. Install FFmpeg and dependencies:

```
# sudo yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel mplayer mencoder flvtool2 libogg libvorbis lame
# sudo yum install make plesk-php56-devel gcc glibc-devel zlib-devel
```

4. Download `ffmpeg-php`:

```
# git clone https://github.com/nilsringersma/ffmpeg-php
# cd ffmpeg-php 
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/phpize
```

5. Do `configure` & `make`:

```
# ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php-config --enable-skip-gd-check
# make 
# make install
```

6. Enable the extension:

```
# echo "extension=ffmpeg.so" > /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/ffmpeg.ini
# plesk bin php_handler --reread
```

For more general instructions, refer to [this guide](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005875373).

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to, you just could use `shell_exec` to run ffmpeg on php

You can follow this link

[Running ffmpeg command using shell_exec in php as a background process in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872943/running-ffmpeg-command-using-shell-exec-in-php-as-a-background-process-in-window)

Comment: i am using CentOS